# How to print all the values of hashset using C? I have stored the string in the hashset now I want to display it

Tags: c, hashset

```
hashset *newset= new_hashset;
char *info="1234";
put_hashset (newset,info);
```

I took the help from [here](https://people.ucsc.edu/~jinnis/hashset.c). I have inserted values in the hashset but I am not being able to print the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a standard hashtable structure. A size, plus an array of linked lists. So you ned to iterate over the array, then over the lists (mosts of the lists will be short and some will be empty). The data is in no particular order.

```
void getdata(hashset *hash)
{
   int i;
   hashnode *ptr;

   for(i=0;i<hash->size;i++)
   {
       if(hash->chains[i])
       {
          for(ptr = hash->chains[i]; ptr; ptr = ptr->link)
          {
             printf("key : %s\n", ptr->word);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it prints the value. But why is it printing only one value?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at it's [header file](https://people.ucsc.edu/~jinnis/hashset.h), the API doesn't include that kind of operation. All you can do is check if a string is in the set, there's no support for iterating over all added strings.

You can do:

```
hashset *newset = new_hashset(); /* You need this! */
char * const info = "1234";
put_hashset(newset, info);
printf("%s\n", has_hashset(newset, "1234") ? "yes" : "no");
```

And it should print `yes`.

Of course you could add support for iterating, but that is a bit beyond the scope of this question. It's not exactly hard, but you'd need to understand the design of the hashset.

Comment: I want to print the info that i inserted in the "newset" using put_hashset function. Suppose I added "1234", "4567", "67345" in the hashset, how do I print all the values that I previously inserted.

Comment: @sophina I did answer that: you can't, not with the hashset's code as given. There is no ready-made function for you to call do do that. You must write it yourself, and that will require understanding the hashset's internals, i.e. how the data structure works.